# How to properly use 3rd party javascript libraries in Angular 6+

Tags: javascript, angular, reference, global, angular-cli-v6

I would like to use some 3rd party libraries in my Angular project, but since version 6 of Angular I get the reference error: global not defined. I've installed the library and added the @types library too. Unfortunately I didn't get it to work yet.

Is there anyone who can explain to me how to use 3rd party libraries in angular 6 and higher? I don't want to revert back to Angular 5 just for a javascript library.

Comment: which 3rd party library are you using?

Answer (score 1):

add this to your index.html

```
<script>
  if (global === undefined) {
    var global = window;
  }
</script>
```

from: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/678

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've seen this solution come up on various threads but adding this script raises a TypeError: superCtor is undefined. I also tried to add (window as any).global = window; to the polyfill.ts but it also raises the TypeError.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Have you find a solution yet? I'm planning to migrate a project from Angular 4 to 6 and knowing that issues (specially ones involving 3rd party libs) may arise I'm hesitant to do so

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to use it depends on what you need exactly.

Generally speaking for those legacy un-typed js library you can always use something like the following:

`import * as jquery from 'jquery'`

For libraries that require global access, you might need to tweak `angular.json` file and add reference to `scripts` field:

```
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/zoomooz/jquery.zoomooz.min.js"
],
```

For some tricky library with default export statements, you might even need to do:

`import LIBRARYNAME from 'library-name'` (without brackets)

So it really depends on what you need.